# How to clean-up the Unity menu?

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome

At some time I've installed Gnome Shell. After some time of fiddling with it, I've decided that I prefer Unity, so I've uninstalled it. Now the Unity menu is full of strange icons with no descriptions. There's also some duplicates of programs, such as Gimp or Gedit. How do I clean my menu, and possibly my system of all that's left behind by Gnome?

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

I'm using 11.10/64. Please let me know if there's more info I can provide.

Comment: what do you have in here, run command Without quotes  "ls ~/.local/share/applications"

Comment: I've given up trying to clean it, and that, with a couple of other minor problems made me decide to do a clean install while my system was still fresh. I'm sorry I won't be much help solving this problem.

Comment: It's alright. By the way, a history of installed packages can be seen in the Ubuntu Software Center. It might be a good reference in the future if you want to remove packages recently installed.

Answer (score 0):

That's a messy Unity.

As far as I know, Gnome Shell is by default included in the Ubuntu 11.10 CD so you actually did not need to install it. The excess packages can be automatically cleaned up by executing

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

and/or

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Thanks! autoclean returned a list of removed files and autoremove nothing. My menu is still messy, even after a logout and a restart.